# Unable to install Ubuntu (and other Linux distro)

Tags: system-installation

recently I got interested in Linux and I wanted to install a beginners-friendly distribution. So I first decided to install Deepin, but it **got stuck at the loading logo** and nothing from the solutions worked. I've tried to install other distributions like Mint Cinnamon, Manjaro and Ubuntu, but the instalation ended the same way - **it loads, shows the logo and freezes**/ gets stuck. I did the installations via **bootable USB Drive**. My laptop is **ASUS K550V (Intel Core i7-6700HQ - 3.5Gz; 8GB RAM; nVidia GTX 950M)**. Smart Boot from BIOS was disabled by default.

Comment: With Ubuntu, are you reaching the menu to select "try" or "install" Ubuntu?

Comment: Also, are you able to reinstall Windows through USB (just to prove out that the hardware is generally working correctly?

Comment: Make usb bootable in UEFI mode and retry.

Comment: I tried on any linux distro to try and to install, again the loading logo freezes. I wanted to install to alongside with my Windows, so I still have OS on the computer. I'll try, I've made the USB in Rufus and the option was BIOS/UEFI

Comment: I've made my USB with GTP/UEFI and I managed to successfully install Ubuntu, but when I choose to format everything ( to have only ubuntu) it promped that I will be unable to boot BIOS OS, if installed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem might be with your GPU. By default, Nouveau drivers are installed for Nvidia GPUs and they might cause problems completing boot even during installation.

1. Switch on and enter GRUB (the bootloader).
   [image]
2. select the option "**try Ubuntu**" but do not click or press enter.
3. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the entry.
4. Come to the line that includes `quiet splash`, delete it and write
   `nomodeset`
   [image]
5. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to boot.

If it works you need to do it once again
    after you install Ubuntu. (After doing that you can choose proprietary
    Nvidia driver and get rid of this problem.)